# I am trying to use Miktex in Manim but it asks me to download random packages

Tags: python, command-prompt, manim, miktex

I have started using Miktex and it does not work. How do I apply it to Manim?
[image]

When I try to use my code, it tells me to download random packages, and keeps on giving the random packages until I have to press cancel. Is there any way to resolve this problem?? Thanks, Jake.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem, though how much time was wasted: is to keep spamming install until you're able to use it.

Comment: You can un-tick the "Always show this dialog" box, to only have to click Install once.